# WIX dynamically set install path according to registry key

Tags: wix, windows-installer, registry

I am using WIX to generate an MSI to install an application. I want the application to be installed in a subfolder of a previously installed application. The issue is that the path for this previously installed application can be changed at install time (the UI provides a directory selection dialog); the path is however saved in a registry key. How can I get the value of this registry key and use it as TARGETDIR value for my new application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should take a look at the [RegistrySearch](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/wix_xsd_registrysearch.htm) element. And by the way, [this paragraph of the WiX tutorial](http://www.tramontana.co.hu/wix/lesson1.php#1.5) describes the approach you should follow in such situations.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

I'd use a [ComponentSearch](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix2/wix_xsd_componentsearch.htm) and set the result in TARGETDIR using a custom action.